# Magento2 - How to update the value of an option of a product attribute programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rest-api

I'm using the `REST` api and believe that we can't update the value of an option of a product attribute: we only have the `POST` method and no `PUT`.

So, what would be the best way to do it in code?

In fact, I would like to create a `custom API` endpoint to do that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which API end point you are referring ?

Comment: @Pawan Thanks, is products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options